How can I stub a function that belongs to a class in an external dependency?
I want to test a Google Cloud Function written in Typescript, and the function calls publishMessage, a member function of the Topic class. How can I make a unit test capture the argument that got passed to publishMessage so that I can validate it?
I've tried to understand how to do it using sinon or proxyquire, but all the examples are using javascript's require() and/or are stubbing module-level static functions. I don't understand how that maps to using Typescript's import and to stubbing a method that's inside of a class.
The code I want to test looks something like this:
import {PubSub} from "@google-cloud/pubsub"

class Foo {
    private pubSub = new PubSub()
    private topic = this.pubSub.topic("foo-topic")

    public publishMessage() {
        const data = Buffer.from("content")
        return this.topic.publishMessage({data})
    }
}

const foo = new Foo()

// This function is what the test will have access to and operate on.
export const fooPublishMessage = foo.publishMessage

In case it matters, I'm using mocha and chai for testing, but I'm not married to them.

The technique you're trying to implement is called "dependency injection" if you want to do web searches to learn more about that. You will want to mock the pubsub dependency so that you can capture calls to it.

TL;DR: Wrap the dependency and stub your wrapper; don't try to stub the dependency.
The solution I found was to:

Stop putting everything in classes like I'm using Java.
Wrap the call to the external code in a module-level function, and make that function as thin as possible.
Use sinon to stub that wrapper function--not to stub the third-party library.

// My wrapper module, PubSub.ts
const pubSub = new PubSub()
export async function publishBytes(topicName: string, bytes: Uint8Array): Promise<void> {
    const topic = pubSub.topic(topicName)
    const data = Buffer.from(bytes)
    await topic.publishMessage({ data })
}

// My test code
import * as PubSub from "./PubSub"
sinon.spy(PubSub, "publishBytes")...


You don't. Google already took care of it. They unit test their own stuff.
I think the question you're trying to ask is, how do I test my component when it depends on another. Well, you know PubSub return type. I'm certain you can mock that out and test it yourself. No?
